# Find $ \arg\left( \frac{e^{-s}}{s + e^{-s}} \right)$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm having problems with finding:
$$ \arg\left( \frac{e^{-s}}{s + e^{-s}} \right)$$

I would say that $e^{-s}$ does not have a impact in this so that the argument should be $\arctan{1}$. But I can't get my calculations to comply.

The real question is to find $\omega_0$ in $\arg(G_0(i\omega_0)) = - \pi$. I know that the answer should be $1.57$ rad/s.

Where $G_0 = \frac{e^{-s}}{s + e^{-s}} $

Comment: What do you mean by arg(arg(x))?

Comment: Sorry the I got two arguments in there. I'll edit it.

Comment: Sorry to ask again: What is $G_0$?

Comment: I've made the question a bit more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The requirement that $\arg (G_0(i\omega_0))=-\pi$ is equivalent to the requirement that $G_0(i\omega_0) $ is a negative real. $\omega_0=\frac{\pi}{2}$ meets this requirement.

Note that $e^{-i\frac{\pi}{2}}=-i.$ So,

$$ \frac{e^{-s}}{s + e^{-s}} =\frac{-i}{i\frac{\pi}{2}-i}=\left(\frac{i}{i}\right)\frac{-i}{i\frac{\pi}{2}-i}=\frac{1}{1-\frac{\pi}{2}}<0.$$